# Lower Bounding a computation problem

Tags: optimization, algorithms, computer-science, computational-complexity

I was looking for the computational complexity of the [Mutilated Chessboard Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutilated_chessboard_problem) waiting to find an upper bound in order to know which category of complexity the problem belonged to.

What i found is instead a [paper](https://core.ac.uk/download/pdf/82360592.pdf) where the author proves an exponential lower bound for this problem.
Is specificing lower bound a way to show that the problem belongs to a certain complexity's category (NP-Hard in this case) ?